# Probability that the convex hull of random points contains sphere's center

Tags: geometry, geometric-probability

What is the probability that the convex hull of $n+2$ random points on $n$-dimensional sphere contains sphere's center?

Comment: On the surface of the sphere? (And a 1-dimensional sphere = circle right?)

Comment: @KennyTM: The circle is the two dimensional sphere, I think. Otherwise the answer would be 0.

Comment: @Jens fixed, thanks (for 1-dimensional sphere should be 3 points, of course)

Comment: @KennyTM Yes (to both questions)

Comment: This is probably a question more suited to Math Overflow.

Comment: @Noldorin: What makes you think this question is not suitable here?  

(Unrelated comment: this result (Wendel's theorem) is also proved (similar to the answers below) in *The art of mathematics: coffee time in Memphis* by Béla Bollobás, [p. 315-317](http://books.google.com/books?id=ButlynVk25MC&pg=PA315) (currently inaccessible).)

Comment: Related: [video](https://youtu.be/OkmNXy7er84) from 3Blue1Brown

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is one of those old chestnuts that come up again and again.
To be precise, the probability that the convex hull of $n+2$ points in $S^n$
(the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$) contains the origin is $2^{-n-1}$.

There's a brief argument at [Wolfram's mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphereTetrahedronPicking.html) which I don't find
entirely convincing but which certainly can be patched to form
a convincing argument. In brief, show that for random points $P_1,\ldots,P_{n+2}$
on the sphere, then with probability one, exactly one choice of signs
will put the centre in the convex hull of $\pm P_1,\pm P_2,\ldots,\pm P_{n+1}$
and $P_{n+2}$.

**Added** (3/8/2010)
Thanks to Grigory for his comment. Changing the notation slightly,
one can show that under some fairy weak hypotheses, if we choose $m+1$
points randomly and indepedently in $\mathbb{R}^m$ the probability their convex
hull contains the origin is $2^{-m}$.

Take a probability distribution on $\mathbb{R}^m$ and choose a sequence
of points (which we identify with vectors) independently from that distribution.
Our first condition on this distribution is that $m$ vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_m$
chosen independently from it are linearly independent with probability one.
This can fail if say some point occurs with nonzero probability or the
distribution lies in a hyperplane through the origin. Assume this condition.

Now a sequence $v_0,v_1,\ldots,v_m$ of random points chosen according to
our distribution are linearly dependent: there are reals $a_i$ not all zero with
$\sum_i a_i v_i=0$. By our condition, with probability one, the sequence
$(a_0,\ldots,a_m)$ is unique up to constant multiple, and moreover all the
$a_i$ are nonzero. So we may assume $a_0=1$ and $a_1,\ldots,a_m$
are nonzero and uniquely determined. Then the convex hull of the $v_i$
contains the origin if an only if all the $a_i$ are positive.

Now we introduce another condition: that the distribution is centrally symmetric;
in detail the probability that a random vector $v$ lies in a set $A$ equals
the probability that $-v$ lies in $A$. A condition like this is clearly necessary;
it stops the distribution being supported on a small region far from the origin.
This condition shows that all the $2^m$ possibilities of signs
for $a_1,\ldots,a_m$ are equiprobable; since changing the sign of some
$v_i$ changes the sign of $a_i$.

To conclude, if our probability distribution on $\mathbb{R}^m$ satisfies
these two condition, the probability that the convex hull of $m+1$
indepdendently chosen points contains the origin is $2^{-m}$.
These conditions are satisfied by the uniform distribution on a sphere
with centre at the origin, but also by many others.

Comment: To make it more convincing one may add some words about barycentric coordinates: a point O lies inside a convex hull of $P_1,...,P_{n+2}$ iff all of its barycentric coordinates (w.r.t. these points) are positive (and switching sign of $P_i$ is almost the same thing as switching sign of i-th barycentric coordinate of O).

Answer (score 17):

This problem is discussed in [J. G. Wendel; A Problem in Geometric Probability, Mathematica Scandinavica 11 (1962) 109-111](http://www.mscand.dk/article/view/10655/8676). Wendel showed that the probability of $N$ random points lying on the surface of the unit sphere in dimension $n$ all lie on one hemisphere is

$2^{-N+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {{N-1}\choose k}$

I've found this [here](http://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~sillke/PUZZLES/ranpoint.txt).

Comment: interesting generalization, thanks