# Area bounded by $\cos x+\cos y=1$

Tags: definite-integrals, area, geometric-probability, trigonometric-integrals

What is the area of the region $\cos x+\cos y > 1$, where $|x|,|y|<\pi$?

[image: Visualization of region (cos x + cos y > 1) and |x| < pi/2 and |y| < pi/2, by Wolfram Alpha]

In other words, is there a "closed" form -- using functions that are well-known and nice to work with -- for this integral?
$$4\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{-1}(1-\cos x)\,dx = 7.2948823845\ldots$$

I can approximate it pretty well:

```
>>> scipy.integrate.quad(func=lambda x: math.acos(1-math.cos(x)),
...                      a=0, b=math.pi/2,
...                      epsabs=1e-14, epsrel=1e-13, limit=200)
(1.8237205961260357, 1.0436096431476471e-14)
```

times 4:

```
(7.294882384504143, 4.1744385725905886e-14)
```

These numbers don't appear in Inverse Symbolic Calculator, OEIS, or Google.

I ask this question because finding the area of $(\cos x + \cos y > M)$ for a variable $M$ is an intermediate step towards a solution to this question: [What is the chance that an $n$-gon whose vertices lie randomly on a circle's circumference covers a majority of the circle's area?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2388421/what-is-the-chance-that-an-n-gon-whose-vertices-lie-randomly-on-a-circles-cir) I figure that if there's any chance that this area is a reasonable function of $M$, then it should have a reasonable value when $M=1$!

*Edit:* In the comments, LCFactorization found this form:
$$\frac{8}{9\sqrt{\pi}}\left(
9\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2{}_4F_3\left( \begin{array}{c}\frac14,\frac14,\frac34,\frac34\\\frac12,\frac54,\frac54\end{array};\frac14\right)
+
\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^2{}_4F_3\left( \begin{array}{c}\frac34,\frac34,\frac54,\frac54\\\frac32,\frac74,\frac74\end{array};\frac14\right)
\right)$$
How can we humans derivate that expression from the integral? And can it be simplified?

*Edit<sup>2</sup>*: And how can one get a symbolic integration engine to handle such an integral? In Mathematica, the inputs `Integrate[
 Boole[Cos[x] + Cos[y] > 1], {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {y, -Pi/2, Pi/2}]` and `Integrate[ArcCos[1 - Cos[x]], {x, 0, Pi/2}]` just output integrals again. How do you hint to it to try crazy hypergeometric functions?

Comment: I tried `Mathematica` and obtained: $$\frac{8}{9\sqrt{\pi}}\left(9\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2_4\cdot{\rm{HypergeometricPFQ}}\left(\color{blue}{\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4}};\frac{1}{2},\frac{5}{4},\frac{
5}{4};\color{red}{\frac{1}{4}}\right)+\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^2_4\cdot{\rm{HypergeometricPFQ}}\left(\color{blue}{\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4}};\frac{3}{2},\frac{7}{4},\frac{7}{4};\color{red}{\frac{1}{4}}\right)\right)$$

Comment: @LCFactorization Wow, that's... something! What does that subscript on the gamma function mean, e.g. the last $4$ in $\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2_4$?

Comment: Something might be wrong when I convert it into TeXForm. The original mathematica expression of the result is `1/(9 Sqrt[\[Pi]])8 (9 Gamma[3/4]^2 HypergeometricPFQ[{1/4,1/4,3/4,3/4},{1/2,5/4,5/4},1/4]+Gamma[5/4]^2 HypergeometricPFQ[{3/4,3/4,5/4,5/4},{3/2,7/4,7/4},1/4])`

Comment: @LCFactorization Ah, okay! To 50 digits, that's 7.29488238450413994801832163352832279686925221538657...

Comment: @LCFactorization By the way, how did you get Mathematica to output that? I just tried `Integrate[ArcCos[1 - Cos[x]], {x, 0, Pi/2}]` on 11.0, and it took about an hour trying to evaluate it, finally just echoing the same expression as output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write the implicit equation into parametric form:
$$\begin{cases}
x(t)=t\\
y(t)=\pm\arccos(1-\cos t)
\end{cases}\quad t\in [-\dfrac{\pi}2,\dfrac{\pi}2]\tag{1}$$

The curve looks like:

[image]

Use Green's theorem,

$${\rm Area}=4\int_0^{\tfrac{\pi}2}x(t){\rm d}y(t)=4\int_0^{\tfrac{\pi}2}\dfrac{-t \;\sin t\; {\rm d}t}{\sqrt{(2-\cos t) \cos t}}\tag{2}$$

Substitute $u=\cos t$,  $t=\arccos u$:

$${\rm Area}=4\int_0^1 \dfrac{\arccos  u}{\sqrt{2 u-u^2}}{\rm d}u \tag{3}$$

Then calculate (3) in Mathematica you can obtain the desired output:

> (1/(9 Sqrt[[Pi]]))8 (9 Gamma[3/4]^2 HypergeometricPFQ[{1/4, 1/4, 3/4, 3/4}, {1/2, 5/4, 5/4}, 1/4] + Gamma[5/4]^2 HypergeometricPFQ[{3/4, 3/4, 5/4, 5/4}, {3/2, 7/4, 7/4}, 1/
>        4])

Comment: Thanks! I'll probably ask a separate question to prove that the last integral indeed equals the output. By the way, you may want to apply your talents here as well: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2388421

Comment: Followup question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2395145