# Enclosing the origin with a random sample

Tags: probability, geometry

Suppose we take the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, centered at the origin, and we start sampling points on its surface uniformly and independently at random.  As an asymptotic function of $n$, how many points will we need to sample before the origin is enclosed by the convex hull of the sampled points, with probability $\ge .5$?

Comment: This may be related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1400/probability-that-the-convex-hull-of-random-points-contains-spheres-center