# Probability of lies a point in a random triangle

Tags: probability, geometry

We have a square. we will opt three random point from inside of this square and name it $p_{1},p_{2},p_{3}$ then opt another random point $p_{4}$. what is the probability of that $p_{4}$ lies in triangle $p_{1}p_{2}p_{3}$ ?

I write program and test it 10 times and in each case test it for $10^{7}$ points and the results are:

```
TEST CASE # 1 = 0.076566
TEST CASE # 2 = 0.076430
TEST CASE # 3 = 0.076308
TEST CASE # 4 = 0.076378
TEST CASE # 5 = 0.076433
TEST CASE # 6 = 0.076340
TEST CASE # 7 = 0.076289
TEST CASE # 8 = 0.076382
TEST CASE # 9 = 0.076402
TEST CASE #10 = 0.076260
```

Comment: I believe this is sufficient to answer your question. http://people.missouristate.edu/lesreid/Adv41.html

Once you have the expected area, the probability $p_{4}$ lies in your triangle should follow.

Comment: @JessicaK. This looks like magics to me ! Thanks for the link.

Comment: @JessicaK: Link not available, are there some regional restrictions on that site? Other link to and partial answer at http://www.rqna.net/qna/pkzyz-expected-area-of-a-triangle-determined-by-randomly-placed-points.html

Comment: Link's not working for me either. Looks like a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28045/expected-area-of-a-triangle-determined-by-randomly-placed-points) was asked before, which has that link.

Comment: Are you looking for an exact answer, in a formula, or just an approximation? What did the original question ask for, or was it just curiosity?

Comment: @LutzL The link works fine for me, I do not know why it would not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [mathworld link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SquareTrianglePicking.html) and a [paper](http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:644463/FULLTEXT01.pdf) answers the question.

$$
\mathbb{P} = \frac{11}{144} \approx 0.0763889
$$