# Probability of Intersecting Two Random Segments in a Circle

Tags: probability, geometric-probability

I designed this problem and tried to solve it but didn't solve.

Choose four points $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ from inside of a circle uniformly and independent. What is the probability that $AC$ intersects $BD$?

[image]

Comment: Even if you remove the circle, the problem would remain same. So what is the purpose of it. And according to me the probability would be infinitesimally small.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal  The circle constrains the locations of the points.  the probability is *not* infinitesimally small!

Comment: Using circle let us to take points uniformly from an area, and you can not take uniform points from $\mathbb{R}^2$. I think probability is near $\frac{1}{5}$. @AdityaAgarwal

Comment: But there is no restriction on the radius of circle.? @DavidG.Stork

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal  Indeed, the problem is scale invariant.  As such, set the circle's radius arbitrarily to $r = 1$.  Alternatively, realize that for a very large circle, the range of positions where the lines can intersect increases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 general cases here, either one point lies in the triangle formed by the other 3, or there is no such point.  The diagram above is an example of the second case.  In the first case, there is no way to connect the line points with 2 lines segments, such that the segments intersect.  In the second case, it is possible, but only in the case where "opposite" points are chosen, which is 1 out of 3 possible.  So, if the probability of having no point lie in the interior of the triangle formed by the other 3 is $P$, the probability is $\frac{1}{3}P$.  Now the trick is how to find $P$.

[edit] As Jack notes below, this separate problem has been solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1243160/expected-area-of-triangle-formed-by-three-random-points-inside-unit-circle), yielding 
$$P=1−\frac{35}{48 \pi^2}$$

Comment: I agree this is the most natural approach. By this related question, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1243160/expected-area-of-triangle-formed-by-three-random-points-inside-unit-circle, we should have $$ P =1-\frac{35}{48\pi^2}. $$

Comment: @Paul. I have an advice: Please remove your idea that has been written as an answer, and write it as a comment behind the main post.

Comment: @mathstudent, first, it is too long to be a comment, and second, as a partial answer it maks more sense to be here.  And with Jack's comment below the answer, everything you need is here.

Comment: @Paul Aha! I was thinking that the jacks comment does not complete the solution, but when I read it again now I found that the solution is completed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Paul if you like, you can edit your answer and write a text behind it to refer to Jacks solution.

Comment: The question linked in the comments shows that the probability that one particular point is in the triangle formed by the other three is $35/(48\pi^2)$. Since there are four possibilities for that point, shouldn't we instead have $P=1-\frac{35}{12\pi^2}$?