# Randomly dropping needles in a circle?

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics, geometric-probability

> If we were to randomly drop $n$ needles of random length in a circle,
>   what would be the odds of finding $k$ intersections? This can be asked
>   as:
>
> Randomly place $n$ line segments in a circle. Their length and position is
>   determined by $2$ random points uniformly and independently set in that circle. What are the odds
>   that we will find $k$ intersections?

---

After seeing the main part of the [calculation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1247948) for what I believe to be the [solution for $P(2,1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1259308), I gave up on calculating $P(n,k)$ because the things behind it are out of my scope (*we barely started mentioning integrals*).

But I still want to find the $P(n,k)$.

---

*Trying to first calculate the same thing, but with points always being on the circle, seems like a simpler thing to do first: [Connecting random points on a circle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2200308/connecting-random-points-on-a-circle)*