# How was "Number of ways of arranging n chords on a circle with k simple intersections" solved?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, geometric-probability

*The problem whose solution is based on the solution to the problem in the title came up as I was trying to find a simpler variant of my [needle problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2199920/randomly-dropping-needles-in-a-circle).*

---

> I we were to uniformly, randomly and independently set $2n$ points on
>   a circle, and then randomly connect them in a way such that each point
>   has its own pair, what would be the odds of finding $k$ intersections?

---

Based on the maximum number of intersections we see that if $k \gt \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$, $P=0$. Otherwise we have some $P>0$.

When connecting the points, all that matters is the ordering of points.

---

### Data Analysis

I can write $P(n,k) = a / b$.

Then $b$ is the number of ways to connect the points uniquely, and $a$ is the number of cases with $k$ intersections for $n$ lines.

There are $b = (2n-1)!!$ ways of connecting the points uniquely.

I wrote a [piece of code](http://pastebin.com/0mGCW0hW) in java to try to brute-force solutions of $a$, for $n$ up to $10$.

I wrote them out in a [spreadsheet](https://justpaste.it/14u54) as a image. Here is the [raw data](https://justpaste.it/14u51) as text.

After closely analyzing the values of $a$, **OEIS** provided me with a sequence. Looks like someone already calculated $a$ which actually is the [*number of ways of arranging n chords on a circle with k simple intersections*](https://oeis.org/A067310).

But the given formula is not correct given as it is.

---

Thanks to [Paul](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/42723/paul) for fixing up a valid [formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2205584), since the OEIS one I stumbled upon seems to be wrong.

> The formula for $P(n,k)$ then is:
>
> $$ \frac{\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{\left\lfloor \tfrac12 +
>  \tfrac12\sqrt{1+8k} \right\rfloor} (-1)^j \cdot
>  \binom{n+k-1-\binom{j}{2}}{n-1} \cdot  \left( \binom{2n}{n+j} -
>  \binom{2n}{n+j-1} \right)}{(2n-1)!!} $$
>
> Which solves my initial problem.
>
> But I'm still curious to know how someone came up with this in the
>   first place, starting out with just a circle and some cords? Regarding the title; **How was** "*Number of ways of arranging n chords on a circle with k simple intersections*" **solved** to produce the expression in the numerator?

Comment: The situations when multiple lines have the same intersection point are obviously a subset of measure 0 and have probability 0. As for your question in general, that's quite a decent problem.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Thanks for clearing that out! Is it then correct to conclude that the only thing that matters is how you pair them up, making their relative random positions on the circle irrelevant?

Comment: The only thing that should matter here is the ordering of the points, so you can fix $2n$ points in general position on the circle, choose one which you call $0$, and then number the other $2n-1$ by choosing an element of $S_{2n-1}$ with uniform distribution and linking $0$ with $1$, $2$ with $2$ and so on. This reduces the problem to a context where you only have $(2n-1)!$ possibilities. However, I'm not sure about how to proceed from here.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud That's what I thought and proceeded to calculate the $P$ by hand for $n$ up to $4$. You mean $(2n-1)!!$ possibilities?

Comment: No, I mean $(2n-1)!$. The possible positions should be the same as a choice of numbering of $2n-1$ points by what I said above. I might be wrong, though.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud There are $3$ ways to **uniquely** connect $4$ points in pairs. There are $5\times3$ unique ways to connect $6$ points in pairs. $7\times5\times3$ for $8$ points and so on. Right?

Comment: Yes you are right, I might be counting some things twice with my approach.

Comment: Another possible approach: adding a chord is the same as cutting the circle in two. So you could reduce the problem of finding $P(n+1,k)$ to finding $P(m,\ell)$ for $m<n$ and $\ell<k$.

Comment: One comment: expectation is linear, and one can work out that for four points, the probability of an intersection is $\frac13$. So the expected number of intersections is $\frac13 \frac{n(n-1)}2$.

Comment: @GregMartin:  there are $n \choose 4$ sets of four points, so the expected number is $\frac 13 {n \choose 4}$

Comment: @RossMillikan you're right, nice catch!

Answer (score 3):

The formula you found on OEIS doesn't seem to be right. I don't know how to derive a formula for your problem,
but I can present a valid formula I found. I will also transform it into an other formula that might be easier.

The OEIS page you give links to [an other OEIS page](https://oeis.org/A067311), which contains more information. The value $a(n, k)$ is calculated by calculating the coefficients of the [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) of a function. I have no idea how they came up with this.
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
f_n(q) &=& (1-q)^{-n} \cdot \sum_{j=-n}^n (-1)^j \cdot \binom{2n}{n+j} \cdot q^{j(j-1)/2} \\
a(n, k) &=& \frac{{f_n}^{(k)}(0)}{k!}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
We can calculate the derivatives:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
g_n(q) &=& (1-q)^{-n} \\
{g_n}^{(k)}(0) &=& \frac{(n+k-1)!}{(n-1)!} \\
h_n(q) &=& \sum_{j=-n}^n (-1)^j \cdot \binom{2n}{n+j} \cdot q^{j(j-1)/2} \\
{h_n}^{(k)}(0) &=& \sum_{j=-n}^n (-1)^j \cdot \binom{2n}{n+j} \cdot k! \cdot 0^{j(j-1)/2-k} \\
{f_n}^{(k)}(q) &=& \sum_{i=0}^k \binom{k}{i} \cdot {g_n}^{(k-i)}(q) \cdot {h_n}^{(i)}(q) \\
s(k) &=& \left\lfloor \tfrac12 + \tfrac12\sqrt{1+8k} \right\rfloor \quad\text{(inverse of } j(j-1)/2 \text{ )} \\
{f_n}^{(k)}(0) &=& \sum_{i=0}^k \binom{k}{i} \cdot \frac{(n+k-i-1)!}{(n-1)!} \cdot
\sum_{j=-n}^n (-1)^j \cdot \binom{2n}{n+j} \cdot i! \cdot 0^{j(j-1)/2-i} \\
&=& \sum_{j=1-s(k)}^{s(k)} \binom{k}{j(j-1)/2} \cdot \frac{(n+k-j(j-1)/2-1)!}{(n-1)!} \cdot
(-1)^j \cdot \binom{2n}{n+j} \cdot (j(j-1)/2)! \\
&=& k! \sum_{j=1-s(k)}^{s(k)} (-1)^j \cdot \binom{n+k-j(j-1)/2-1}{n-1} \cdot
 \binom{2n}{n+j} \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$
So the complete formula becomes:
$$
P(n,k) = \frac{\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{\left\lfloor \tfrac12 + \tfrac12\sqrt{1+8k} \right\rfloor} (-1)^j \cdot \binom{n+k-1-\binom{j}{2}}{n-1} \cdot
 \left( \binom{2n}{n+j} - \binom{2n}{n+j-1} \right)}{(2n-1)!!} 
$$

Comment: If they are computing the Taylor series of a function, they are probably using generating functions methods (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function)