# Average area of a random circle inside a triangle

Tags: probability, integration, geometry, geometric-probability

Pick a random point inside a triangle $(0,0)(1,0)(0,1)$ (with uniform distribution) and draw a largest circle around it, which fully lies inside the triangle. What is the expected value of the circle area?

> I solved the problem, but I don't have an answer to check my solution. Numerical experiments are not really conclusive.

[image]

Let $r$ be the radius of the circle. Then we have three distinct regions. They are defined as follows:

$$r_1=x,~~~\text{if }(x,y) \in \Omega_1=\left(x<y \text{ and } y<1-(1+\sqrt{2})x \right)$$

$$r_2=y,~~~\text{if }(x,y) \in \Omega_2=\left(x>y \text{ and } y<(\sqrt{2}-1)(1-x) \right)$$

$$r_3=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (1-x-y)~~~\text{otherwise } ((x,y) \in \Omega_3)$$

I found $r_3$ by minimizing the function:

$$s(x)=\sqrt{(x_0-x)^2+(y_0-1+x)^2}$$

Now about the distribution. Since it's uniform inside the triangle with area equal to $\frac{1}{2}$, we get:

$$f(x,y)=2$$

---

Next, as I understand it, to find the expected value for $r^2$, we need to integrate this function in each region, and then multiply by its area, divided by the area of the triangle and multiplied by $f(x,y)$:

$$<r^2>=4S_1 \int_{\Omega_1} x^2 dy ~dx+4S_2 \int_{\Omega_2} y^2 dy~ dx+2S_3 \int_{\Omega_3} (1-x-y)^2 dy~ dx$$

$$S_1=S_2=\frac{1}{2} \left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right)$$

$$S_3=\frac{1}{2}-S_1-S_2=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{2} \right)$$

Curiously, for the third region the value is twice of that for two other regions combined:

$$4S_1 \int_{\Omega_1} x^2 dy ~dx+4S_2 \int_{\Omega_2} y^2 dy=\frac{17-12 \sqrt{2}}{24}$$

$$2S_3 \int_{\Omega_3} (1-x-y)^2 dy~ dx=\frac{17-12 \sqrt{2}}{12}$$

The answer I get after evaluating all the double integrals, is:

$$<r^2>=\frac{17-12 \sqrt{2}}{8}=0.00368$$

$$\pi <r^2>=0.01156$$

However, the numerical experiments in Mahtematica (using the regions I defined) suggest the value approximately two times larger.

> Can you spot where did I make a mistake? If all the steps are correct, maybe I made a mistake with integration, however I used Mathematica to check them.

---

**Edit**

Thanks to all the comments and answers. So, the correct value is:

$$<r^2>=2 \int_{\Omega_1} x^2 dy ~dx+2 \int_{\Omega_2} y^2 dy~ dx+ \int_{\Omega_3} (1-x-y)^2 dy~ dx$$

$$<r^2>=\frac{10-7 \sqrt{2}}{24}+\frac{10-7 \sqrt{2}}{24}+\frac{5 \sqrt{2}-7}{12}=\frac{3-2 \sqrt{2}}{12}$$

$$\pi<r^2> =0.04492$$

Which is the same value as Henning got by other means. Apparently, my simulation in Mathematica is wrong, I'll check it later.

Comment: The correct formula will be $$ \Bbb{E}[r^2] = \int_{\triangle} r^2 f(x, y) \, dxdy = \sum_{i=1}^{3} \int_{\Omega_i} 2 r_i^2 \, dxdy. $$

Comment: Why are you multiplying the integrals by $4S_1,4S_2$ etc? Suppose the radius of the circle was always 1. Then you would expect your expected value to come out as 1. I would have thought you just take $\int_{\Omega_1}+\int_{\Omega_2}+\int_{\Omega_3}$ and divide the result by $\frac{1}{2}$ (because that is the total area).

Comment: So the areas of the regions don't matter?

Comment: They do matter in a sense: a larger area "contributes more" to the answer through the corresponding integral $\int_{\Omega_i}$ (see the above comments).

Comment: @zhoraster: On the other hand they _don't_ matter in the sense that the expectation is the same for each of the regions separately anyway!

Comment: Linearity of Expectation says: $\mathsf E(A(X,Y))~=~\sum\limits_{i=1}^3\mathsf E(A(X,Y)~\mathbf 1_{(X,Y)\in\Omega_i})$ where $$\mathsf E(A(X,Y)~\mathbf 1_{(X,Y)\in\Omega_i})=\iint_{\Omega_i} A(x,y)~f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d (x,y)$$

Comment: What you *thought* you were doing was $\mathsf E(A(X,Y)) ~=~\sum\limits_{i=1}^3 \mathsf E(A(X,Y)\mid (X,Y)\in\Omega_i)~\mathsf P((X,Y)\in\Omega_i)$ but  $$\underbrace{\mathsf E(A(X,Y)\mid (X,Y)\in\Omega_i)}_{\text{not the integral you used}}~\underbrace{\mathsf P((X,Y)\in\Omega_i)}_{\propto\text{the area of }\Omega_i} ~=~\underbrace{\mathsf E(A(X,Y)~\mathbf 1_{(X,Y)\in\Omega_i)})}_{\text{The integral you used}}$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp, yes you are right, I thought about the conditonal probability

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's consider a simpler problem first:

> If you select a point uniformly in a triangle with base $b$ and height $h$, what is the expected value of the square of the distance from the base?

Simple symmetry and dimensional considerations ought to tell us that this will be independent of $b$ and proportional to $h^2$, so we can compute it by considering the easy case $b=2, h=1$ where the $y$ coordinate varies between $0$ and $1$ with probability distribution function $f(y) = 2(1-y)$, and the expectation we're after is
$$ \int_0^1 2(1-y)y^2\,dy = \int_0^1 (2y^2 - 2y^3)\,dy = \left[ \frac23 y^3 - \frac12 y^4 \right]_0^1 = \frac16$$
so in the case with arbitrary $h$ the expectation will be $\frac16 h^2$.

Now for the full question. In your triangle the point falls into one of three regions with some probability distribution. But each region has the *same* height, namely the inradius of the triangle -- so the expectation is the same in each of the cases.

Thus your answer is simply

> $\dfrac16$ of the area of the inscribed circle.

For the particular triangle in the question, the radius of the incircle is the solution to
$ \sqrt2 r + r = \frac{\sqrt2}2 $, so
$$ r=\frac{\sqrt2}{2+2\sqrt2} $$
and the expected area is
$$ \frac\pi6 \cdot \frac{2}{(2+2\sqrt2)^2} =
\frac{\pi}{3(4+8+8\sqrt2)} = \frac{\pi}{36+24\sqrt2}$$

Answer (score 1):

If $\triangle$ denotes the triangle and $\bigcirc$ the circle, then to be found is:

$$\mathbb{E}\left(\text{area of }\bigcirc\right)=\int_{\triangle}\pi r\left(x,y\right)^{2}f\left(x,y\right)dxdy=2\pi\int_{\triangle}r\left(x,y\right)^{2}dxdy=$$$$2\pi\left[\int_{\Omega_{1}}r\left(x,y\right)^{2}dxdy+\int_{\Omega_{2}}r\left(x,y\right)^{2}dxdy+\int_{\Omega_{3}}r\left(x,y\right)^{2}dxdy\right]=$$$$2\pi\left[\int_{\Omega_{1}}x^{2}dxdy+\int_{\Omega_{2}}y^{2}dxdy+\int_{\Omega_{3}}\left(1-x-y\right)^{2}dxdy\right]$$