# What is the probability that a particular set of integer edge lengths selected from an interval $[1,n]$, can form a triangle?

Tags: probability, geometry

What is the probability that a particular set of integer edge lengths selected from an interval $[1,n]$, can form a triangle? That is, let $a,b,c \in \{1,2, \dots n \}$. What is the probability that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are the side lengths to a triangle?

How might this extend to the case where one selects real number edge lengths from the unit interval? Can I look for a cube then exceed the pyramids from it?

Comment: I think your question is: What is the probability that 3 lengths selected randomly from a set satisfy the triangle inequality? Are we allowed to select the same length twice?

Comment: Yes exactly, and yes we can select the same length twice

Comment: Well... Let's start small... $n=1$. Then $a,b,c \in \{1\}$ which means there's an 100% chance that they satisfy the triangle inequality. 

What about $n=2$?
Note that all lengths will satisfy the triangle inequality except when we select exactly one length equal to $2$. 

That is, $a=b=1, c=2$ fails the triangle inequality. It fails $3$ out of the $8$ cases.

Comment: Duplicate of [Probability that a triangle can be formed from a permutation of three edges of random length](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94965/probability-that-a-triangle-can-be-formed-from-a-permutation-of-three-edges-of-r)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an except from my answer to a similar question:

If A+B > C, you have 100% chance of making a triangle. If A+B=C, the triangle is 2d and does not qualify. If A+B < C, you have three joined line segments that do not meet at two ends. You will have to figure the probabilities of each of these equalities/inequalities and go from there.

Comment: `If A+B > C, you have 100% chance` Not so, try $A=1, B=100, C=10$ for example.

Comment: It should be $A + B > C$ and $|A - B| < C$