# Forming a triangle probabilistically

Tags: probability-theory

What is the probability that if you break a stick at $2$ points the three sides form a triangle?

Is there a technique that avoids calculus?

Comment: Depends.  How do you choose the two points?

Comment: Assuming you choose the two break points points uniformly, this is a well known problem.  Several different solutions can be found [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/2014/if-you-break-a-stick-at-two-points-chosen-uniformly-the-probability-the-three-r)

Comment: @BrianTung case $1$ uniformly random independently and case $2$ pick one point uniformly randomly and pick one of two broken sticks and pick one point uniformly randomly on that stick

Comment: @Turbo  You should add that to the question.  It's not the standard and leads to a different answer.  A discussion of the variants (including yours) can be found [here](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Probability/TriProbability.shtml#Explanation)

Comment: Your specific variant is also discussed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676/probability-that-a-stick-randomly-broken-in-two-places-can-form-a-triangle)

Comment: All three segments can form a triangle, every single time. Are you looking for a particular type of triangle?