# Probability of a piece of stick being a certain size?

Tags: probability

Suppose Alex has a one meter long wooden stick that Alex breaks randomly in two places such that the location of the breaks are independently distributed uniformly along the length of the wooden stick.

**(a) Calculate the probability that one of the pieces will be more than 75 cm.**

---

Is this just $\frac{75}{100}$?

---

**(b) Calculate the probability that the three resulting pieces of the stick can be arranged to form a triangle.**

---

I know the stick cannot form a triangle unless all three pieces are no longer than the sum. But I don't know how to make this into a probability? If $\alpha$ is the first break and $\beta$ is the second break and L is the length of the stick, then $\alpha < \frac{L}{2}$ and $\beta < \frac{L}{2}$. How would I turn this into a probability?

Comment: There are quite a lot of other posts for part b here, e.g. [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/676/357390).

Answer (score 1):

Let the first point be located at a distance of $X$ and the second point be located at a distance of $Y$ from the start of the stick. We know that $X \sim U(0,1)$ and $Y \sim U(0,1)$.

**Part (a)**

For one of the line segments to be more than $0.75$ cm, then the following are the conditions where this is satisfied

$$
X > 0.75 \text{ and } Y > 0.75 \Rightarrow P(X > 0.75, Y > 0.75)=1/16 \\
Y < 0.25 \text{ and } X < 0.25, \Rightarrow P(Y < 0.25, X < 0.25)=1/16 \\
Y - X > 0.75 \text{ if } Y > X\\
X - Y > 0.75 \text{ if } X > Y
$$

To calculate the probability for the latter two conditions, let us visualize this graphically. 
[image: solution_to_part_a]

The area of the two triangles together is
$$2 * \frac{1}{2} * \frac{1}{4} * \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{16}$$
Hence the probability that one line segment is longer than $75$ cm is 
$$3 * \frac{1}{16} = \frac{3}{16}$$

**Part (b)**

For these three line segments to form a triangle, the following conditions must be satisfied

$$
    X + Y - X > 1 - Y   \Rightarrow Y > 1/2 \\
    Y -X + 1 - Y > X \Rightarrow X < 1/2 \\
    X + 1 - Y > Y - X \Rightarrow Y < X + 1/2
$$

This is for the case assuming $Y > X$. We can write another set of 3 equivalent equations for the case $X >Y$. Visualizing these two feasible regions on a graph, we get

[image: solution_to_part_b]

The total area of the shaded figure, and hence the probability that the three line segments form a triangle is

$$2 * \frac{1}{2} * \frac{1}{2} * \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_1$, $X_2$ be the two uniform variables where the breaks happen.

**HINTS:**

(a) No it's far from $75/100$. One case where the biggest stick is 75 cm long is when both $X_1$ and $X_2$ occur before the 25% mark. The probability this happens is $\mathbb{P}(X_1<0.25 \cap X_2<0.25)=\mathbb{P}(X_1<1/4)\mathbb{P}(X_2<1/4)= 1/16$. What are the other possibilities of values for $X_1$ and $X_2$ that would give a piece of more than 75cm, and what are their probabilities?

(b) Your remarks are correct. Maybe it might be better to wonder in which case the stick *cannot* form a triangle. In any case, having solved the question (a) will help you greatly.

Comment: How did you get 1/16 for the first case?

Comment: Ok, so another case could be if $X_1$ comes before 12.5cm and $X_2$ occurs after 87.5cm; the 75cm piece is in the "middle". And the third (and last?), case is when the $X_1$ and $X_2$ occurs after the 75cm mark, so the 75cm is the "first" piece. Am I thinking of this right? Just don't know how you calculated the probability 1/16, but since these are all the same case(?), would the the probability of A just be 3(1/16)?